# Jenkins credentials - How to pass credentials to "cf login" command?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cloud-foundry, jenkins-groovy

Currently we are using, `cf login` command in Jenkins groovy(scripted pipeline), as shown below:

```
def login(url, uName, password, org, space){
    CONNECT = sh (
                    script: "cf login -a ${url} -u \"${uName}\" -p \"${password}\" -o ${org} -s ${space}",
                    returnStatus: true
                    ) == 0

}
```

---

But now Jenkins is configured with below credentials:

[image]
so, we do not require username/password to connect to Pivotal Cloud foundry

---

How to use these credentials in scripted pipeline?

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/

Answer (score 2):

```
def login(url, org, space){

    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'AppsManager', usernameVariable: 'uName', passwordVariable: 'password')]) {
        CONNECT = sh (
                    script: "cf login -a ${url} -u \"${uName}\" -p \"${password}\" -o ${org} -s ${space}",
                    returnStatus: true
                ).trim()
    }

}
```

Comment: Generally, there is an newline at the last line of your bash cmd output.  If the `cf login` cmd output is not `0`, but print out more text.  You should not use `=="0"`. I will remove it from my answer.

Comment: If the command output does not return true, how to assess the result of sh step?